# What mechanisms of action plausibly explain the correlation between SIBO and a CRC?

Tags: pathophysiology, fungal-infection, yeast-infection, sibo

Doctors who treat gut conditions have found that Small Intestinal Bacteria Overgrowth (SIBO) and Candida-Related-Complexes (CRC) often occur in the same people, but as far as I am aware, which, if either, causes the other is not known.  What are the live options for mechanisms of action by which one could cause the other, or both could be caused by some underlying condition?